# Why the GSM Shield is discontinued? What options are available?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I need to build a device with a single button to make a call over a mobile network (GSM)

I wanted to buy an arduino one and an arduino gsm shield for this, but just noticed that the GSM Shield is retired - discontinued.

I checked all the arduino products but there is no options for integration with GSM.

What options do I've to build my products if the GSM Shields is discontinued?

Comment: I don't know about South America, but GSM is obsolete. There are only a few users in most countries, the networks have been cannibalised and will shortly be shut down.

Comment: @Milliways, not really. GSM is a reliable and easy way to communicate. It is not yet obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A retired product is just a product that isn't supported anymore. It doesn't mean that this product is not usable anymore. Because the GSM shield is discontinued by Arduino.cc itself, you could buy Arduino.org ([link](http://www.arduino.org/products/shields/arduino-gsm-shield-2) to the GSM shield 2), or even an other model by Adafruit. Here is a [link](https://www.adafruit.com/?q=gsm%20shield&) for many options of GSM shields on Adafruits' website.

A last option would be to buy it from a chinese seller on Amazon or Ebay. Though they are cheap, they are usualy very crappy and there are not many libraries for them.